# Function that returns structure giving bad return values

Tags: c, function

This is my first post so don't go rough on me if I happened to skip something I should have mentioned.

I am working on a program that simulates a tennis championship, and the outcome of an individual match via a `rand()` function to distribute the points among the 2 players currently in said match.

I have scanned the program and did my best to fix the issues but there is still a problem I can not fix, it is the function that determines the outcome of the matches. The problem is that the function returns strange values, nothing they should look like.

I first thought there is a problem with the declaration of the variables and the way I did operations with them but that did not seem to be the case, so I ran out of ideas and come to you.

Here is the code:

```
jucatori meci(jucatori jucator1,jucatori jucator2 )
{
   int u =0;   //scor jucator 1
   int o=0;    //scor jucator 2

   int p;     //aux j1 
   int l;     //aux j2
   int i;

   do
   {
     //first loop, where player 1 serves
     p= rand() % jucator1.sansaServire;  //generate a number for player1
     l= rand() % jucator2.sansaPrimire;  //generate a number for player2

     if(l>p)
     {
        o=o+1;

        do
        {
           //going into the second loop, in this loop, here, player 2 serves
           p = rand() % jucator1.sansaPrimire;
           l = rand() % jucator2.sansaServire;
           if(p>l) u = u+1;
           if(l>p) o = o+1;
           else break; //iese din bucla 2, juc1 va servi iarasi
        }while(l>p);
    }
    else if(p>l) u = u+1;
  }while(u + o < 51);   //inchidem prima bucla

  if(u > o && u - o > 10)
  {
      jucator1.meciurijucate++;
      jucator2.descalificat = 1;
      jucator1.scor1 = u;
      jucator1.scor2 = o;
      return jucator1;
  } //return player 2, add 1 to the number of matches played and mark player 1 as out of the game
  else if(o > u && o - u > 10)
  {
      jucator2.meciurijucate++;
      jucator1.descalificat = 1;
      jucator2.scor1 = o;
      jucator2.scor1 = u;
      return jucator2;
  }//return player 1, add 1 to the number of matches played and mark player 2 as out of the game
  else return meci(jucator1,jucator2); //call function again if the match is a draw
}
```

I will provide the full program if needed, just thinking that it would be pretty bulky to post the whole thing.

Comment: Is `jucatori` a typedef'd struct? In that case, your parameter structs are copied when you call `meci()`. This also means that e.g. `jucator1.meciurijucate++`has no effect outside of `meci()`, because you are operating on the local copy only. If you want to modified a struct's fields, you need to pass a pointer.

Comment: @dhke, IMO this is not a problem as OP is returning the same type, consider `int fn(int x) {return x;};`

Comment: @KeineLust Hmm, yeah. But that depends on the rest of the code, so I'd though I'd mention it. But yes.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` handle the case where `l > p` and `p < l`. What if `l == p`?

Comment: **The problem is that the function returns strange values, nothing they should look like.** This is not very clear. What values is it returning, what values should it return instead?

Comment: they should look like : Playername, 50,60,3,0 41-9; those being the name, win chance 1, win chance 2, games played, disqualified or not, and the score of the game that the player has just won.
instead I am getting Playername 0, 7237481,0786768,127 - 99
And, if l==p, then the function is called again, within the function

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [mcve]. Bear in mind that every non-English identifier halves your chances to get a useful answer.